# Singular or plural verb following "any" with a plural noun

Tags: grammatical-number, verb-agreement, quantifiers

Is it correct to say "If any of the parties are required,...."?

Is it correct to say, "If any of the parties is required,...."?

Comment: This use of “any” occurs with either singular or plural agreement, so both your examples are fine. The reason is that “any” can function as determiner to both singular and plural nouns:    _**Any lawyer** worth his salt should know that_ ; _Are there **any  letters** for me today?_

Comment: But shouldn’t it be either, “*If any of the parties are required*” or “*If any party is required*”?